# GeoDjango: Speedup GEOS's Geometry operations

Tags: django, optimization, thread-safety, geodjango, geos

I'm developing a spatial ranking application using GeoDjango + PostGIS. Basically what it does is that it retrieves all geometries within the query bounding box, computes the similarity score using a custom function I created, and then return the shapes with top-most scores.

Currently the roundtrip time in each query is very slow. Running profiler shows that the bottleneck is from `threadsafe.py` which are called by `GEOSGeometry` operations (i.e. intersects, unions, contains, etc.) inside my similarity function. Here is example [profiler result](https://gist.github.com/1065129) from a single query. It looks like the thread-safe nature of `GEOSGeometry` is what causing the performance issue here. Individually, the operation taking 40ms doesn't seem like a big deal, but because the number of shapes to compare against the query are usually large, i.e. ~1000 shapes, a 40ms-operation adds up to 40 sec.

Therefore, my question is how can I optimize the function to minimize the turnaround time. Some of my initial ideas are:

1. Turn off / avoid the theadsafety checking of `GEOSGeometry`, as these objects are transient and are not shared to any other thread. This would be the ideal case, if possible, as the majority of time spent now is in `threadsafe.py`
2. Use another geometry API which isn't treadsafe.
3. <strike>Perform spatial operations at PostGIS level instead of object level. This will make the code looks ugly though.</strike> (**Updates:** This option doesn't work. The overhead of SQL queries alone make operation even slower.)

What's your thoughts?

Comment: I tried using `GDALGeometry` which comes with GeoDjango as the alternative to `GEOSGeometry`. `GDALGeometry` turns out to rely on threadsafe.py, and as a result performs even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We switched to using [shapely](https://github.com/sgillies/shapely) for our geos operations. It got us around the threadsafe issue.

FYI, shapely uses long,lat and not lat,long like GeoDjango does

Comment: As shapely depends on GEOS for its spatial operations, I thought that it should suffer the same problem. Interesting. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `threadsafe.py` is just wrapping each call to the underlying C functions. For a better idea of what your bottlenecks are, look at the `cumtime` column. See here for a description of the columns: http://docs.python.org/library/profile.html#module-pstats.

Comment: You're correct that `threadsafe.py` is a wrapper to C functions. I've double checked the profiled result and it's still true that `threadsafe.py` is the bottleneck. I mean, it gets called every time a spatial operation (e.g. intersects, within, union) is called. The time actually spent in these operations are so small comparing to time spent in threadsafe. That's why I was thinking if I could avoid using threadsafety altogether the problem would be solved.